# Powershell CLI launches new window with Python scripts

Tags: windows-10, powershell, python

Usually I run my python scripts on my windows 10 laptop in a powershell CLI. But for some reason after I rebooted last time, every time I run my python scripts it launches a new window.

And if I just want to display a help page the new window disappears before you can read it.

It might be a group policy that my company just pushed out, because my coworker is seeing the same thing.

Is there any way I can stop that from happening by setting an option on the CLI or something?

Comment: How are you running your _Powershell_ Command-Line Interfaces and your Help Pages? Are you using some Desktop Icons? Can you edit them and append to their Command-Line String the `&& pause` Character String? With it, the windows that are popping up on your screen should be paused, so that you are able to read them.

Comment: Well I'm doing a search for `powershell` in the windows search toolbar, and then running it that way. It used to work fine as of this morning. Then I rebooted and that's when the problem started happening.

Comment: Rrright. Then, after you search for it, choose the Down-Pointed Arrow and then the _Open File Location_ Option. Then, you will have a _File Explorer_ Window opened up. Then, search for the _Windows PowerShell_ Icon. Edit it and apply our First Comment.